# Is there a simple way to define "get and set" in Java like C#?

Tags: java, properties

In C#, I Can use a simple way like below

```
public class Dummy 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

but if i use java to do the same thing, i must do like below

```
public class Dummy {
    private String _name;

    public void setName(String value) {
        this._name = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this._name;
    }
}
```

so, you can tell that is at least 7 line codes take the same efftects as 1 line code in c#;
so, i'm wondering at is there a simple way in java that i can use to simple set field or get field?

thx for advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to the language, but you could always use [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/)'s annotation set to generate getters and setters for you at compile-time.

In particular, `@Data` is quite powerful - it generates your getter, setter, and a `toString()` method.

Here's an example:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private final T data;
    private Node<T> left = null;
    private Node<T> right = null;

    public Node(final T theData) {
        data = theData;
    }

    public void add(final Node<T> theNode) {
        if(data.compareTo(theNode.getData()) <= 0) {
            // goes to the left
            left = theNode;
        } else {
            // goes to the right
            right = theNode;
        }
    }
}
```

You may have to install a plugin for your IDE to recognize that this is being generated at compile-time, but this takes care of all of your setter and getter boilerplate code.

Comment: good idea, i'm woking on annotation try to fit the question, thx again

Answer (score 3):

Java does not support that particular C# idiom, however many IDEs include methods to generate accessors and mutators; for example, in eclipse you can select

> Source, Generate Getters and Setters

or

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>   <kbd>r</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

That's is language specific, you cannot expect any more.
There is a simpler way to create get/set just by some clicking:
On eclipse editor, right click to open menu\Source\Generate Getters and Setters 
-> select property that's you want to getter and setter.